# managing panel and window location in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have been having an issue since VS 2012 (currently using 2013) that the panels and windows are constantly all over the place. I have worked with VS for years and this hasn't ever been an issue. I know this has something to do with the .vssettings file but I really don't want to go farting around with it.

I would like something like VSWindowManager PowerToy however that doesn't seem to have been updated since 2006.

Does anyone know how to stabilize the location of windows in panels in VS 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a VS extension called [Layouts O Rama](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c) I have been using it for about a week now. and I am very pleased with it, it seems to have calmed down all the window madness I was experiencing with various windows coming up all over creation.

It can be installed using the extension manager Tools > Extensions and updates.

[image]